# Finding string within String and applying to an Listview

Tags: android, string

I have this particular format.

```
{
    mDevice = 27: 62: 4 A: 9E: CE: 88, mScanRecord = ScanRecord[mAdvertiseFlags = 6, mServiceUuids = null, mManufacturerSpecificData = {
        76 = [5, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 99, -23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }, mServiceData = {}, mTxPowerLevel = -2147483648, mDeviceName = null], mRssi = -88, mTimestampNanos = 335641866574859
}
```

I wish to extract the mDevice name and if it's not null value I want to add it and display in a Listview. How do i do this?

Comment: Is the given format is JSON ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)  if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question.](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: No it's not JSON format. I have put the contents int a string. I found the index. But then trying to add in a listview I m having issue. Plus a a few devices don't have an mDevicename.

Comment: Please describe the complete problem. It's really hard to go through with  incomplete information.